# Media Queries | Defining "Screen"

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've been doing some research on this topic and can't find an answer.

When defining your media queries you typically write the following one of two ways:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {}
```

What I'm interested to learn is what's the reason one would define "screen"? Is this a **must have** when defining media queries?

Also - what is best / common practice regarding using `min-width` or `max-width`?

Google advises to **NOT** use the `min-device-width`property:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "screen" aspect of the media rule is referred to as "media type" and filters contexts in which the styles within the query may be applied.

> A media query consists of a **media type** and zero or more expressions that check for the conditions of particular media features.

The specification does state that the type can be omitted-

> if the media type is not explicitly given **it is ‘all’.**

Therefore, in a strictly technical and "as per the spec" sense, "screen" can be omitted from your media query.

I was once taught that some browsers that do not understand the media query specification have difficulty unless the media type is specified and render all styles regardless. This was about two years ago I am struggling to find any citations and references to it, contemporary or otherwise, so this may not be a worthwhile consideration for you now.

[Version 4 of the media queries specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries/#media-types) deprecates all specific media queries apart from screen, print and speech (largely as the lines between handheld, tv, screen etc are now extremely blurred at best) and states-

> Note: It is expected that all of the media types will also be
>   deprecated in time, as appropriate media features are defined which
>   capture their important differences.

As such, unless your testing uncovers problems with legacy browsers and media queries that do not specify a media type - you should be able to safely omit the type in your stylesheets.

It is worth noting though that your examples are not exactly equal. The example-

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {}
```

Is exactly equivalent to-

```
@media all and (min-width: 320px) {}
```

And not the cited-

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {}
```

As 'all' obviously includes 'screen', the rendered effect is the same in your tests, but it is probably useful to understand that these are **not** equal expressions.

Most notably omitting the type will mean that your styles are applied in print where the remainder of the expression also evaluates to true.

With regard to the advice from Google not to use min-device-width (or indeed I would suggest device-width at all - unless you quite specifically understand what you are doing), this is almost certainly as the width of the device (most often screen) is **not** always the same as the viewport/window in which your page is being rendered.

This will most often be the case, and can most easily be explained, in the context of a laptop or desktop environment where a user has multiple windows open at the same time for the purposes of multi-tasking or copying data between windows. The non-maximized browser window does not fill the full space of the desktop and thus the *window width* is not the same size as the width of the device itself as reported by the browser.

Some tablets and televisions are capable of multi-tasking or multiple side-by-side or window-in-window windows, in particular with tablets running Windows 8, so this is not exclusively a problem in "desktop" environments.

If your media query used the 'device-width' as opposed to simply 'width' then no matter how much the user resizes their window or squishes it about - your design will not change and adapt. The size and resolution of the monitor *remains constant* and as such there will be no change in evaluation of your media query expressions. The only option available to your user in order to change the design would be to maximize the window, change the display resolution on their device (if possible) or to change to another device altogether.

This may well be sub-optimal for the user if viewing a design carefully intended for their full screen width in a window that is substantially smaller - requiring frequent scrolling and/or hiding important content off screen.

The 'width' feature instead targets the actual "display surface", meaning the window size or viewport. As stated in the specification-

> The ‘width’ media feature describes the width of the targeted display
>   area of the output device. For continuous media, this is the width of
>   the viewport

This would mean that a user with a non-maximised window of (say) 40% of the device width would get the design you have chosen for **that** width and not the full 100% width of the device.